# CSS class inherit from anther class

Tags: html, css, class

My question is simple, but I didn't found any documentation about it on Internet. Maybe I didn't search with the right keywords...

Take the example of a CSS class called `centered`, it centers elements and do some other stuff.

I want to say that all the element of the class `news`, for example, inherit from `centered`.

There is several solutions :

- Declare all the elements of `centered` in `news`

  `.centered { X; Y; Z }
  .news { X; Y; Z; A; B }`
- Declare in HTML my tags with the 2 classes :

  `.centered { X; Y; Z }
  .news { A; B }`

  `<div class="news centered">...</div>`

I search a code for doing something like this :

```
.centered { X; Y; Z }
.news { all_the_properties_of_centered; A; B }
```

then I would declare my news with

```
<div class="news">...</div>
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: AFAIK you'll need to use a framework like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass) to do inheritance.

Comment: It's one of the major feature of the preprocessor like sass or less. Css can't do that as far as i know

Comment: Why can't css do that? It easily can

Answer (score 1):

you should take a look at [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/) (or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)) which both can do exactly what you want - and offer a lot of other great possibilitys.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be

```
.centered, .news { X; Y; Z }
.news { A; B }
```

Answer (score 1):

No. CSS doesn't have anything like `extend`. However, you can write it this way

```
.centered, .news { X; Y; Z }
.news { A; B } /* adding rules */
```

Well, actually it does contain `inherit`, but it doesn't mean to inherit from another CSS class, but from default element style, see Hanky Panky's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [Emmet](http://emmet.io/), which was previously known as Zen coding for such combinations. It is fast and very productive if constructed logically.