# Why expected 1px bold for background color?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass

This is my sass:

```
table#orders {
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
```

However, when I actually run this, I got an error saying `Invalid CSS after "#ff0000": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"` I don't know why it is expecting something like 1px for background-color. Can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: The error message is showing *examples* of expressions.  It's not specifically looking for `1px` or `bold`, but it's seeing stuff (specifically the semicolon) following the `#ff0000`, and that stuff doesn't match the syntax of an "expression".

Comment: An error like this would be thrown by the parser, which doesn't yet know about the specific properties you're trying to set.  It just follows rules like "A *property-declaration* consists of a *property-name*, a *colon*, and one-or-more of *expression*".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

probably your sass file extension is *.sass, change to *.scss

*.sass has different syntax, that's why it throws these "crazy" errors.

*.scss support normal css synthax, like yours

if you got interested to learn about these syntax, we have a good question about this:

[What's the difference between SCSS and Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass)

Comment: This is happening to me with *.scss, years later. "Error: Invalid CSS after "...ckground-color:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#008eff12 !importan"
        on line 27 of scss/customdashboard.scss
>>   background-color: #008eff12 !important;"

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to switch from sass to scss, you can change your code to this instead:

```
table#orders 
    background-color:#ff0000
```

this is the right formatting for SASS files.  Here is a link: http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1/

Comment: table#orders 
    background-color: #ff0000  forgot a space after :