# Sass, NOT SCSS in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sass

Can someone please tell me how to get syntax highlighting for .sass, please no .scss help. I have installed every plugin or Nuget package i could find, and they all say sass support. But they mean scss, i wish they did not have the same name, because this is driving me insane.

I can compile .sass just fine, just my file looks like a plain text file.

Lastly, am i crazy or does VS simple not allow you to create a .sass file? I know i can create another file and rename it to .sass, but that seams real real dumb.

Thanks for any help, ill get everyone i know to in the world to up vote your answer lol.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking for an answer. the only plugin that worked for me is [SassyStudio](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d)  it's free and generate css and minification as well.

Answer (score 0):

.scss is the file extension sass is the name

Mindscape Web Workbench has a [visual studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2b96d16a-c986-4501-8f97-8008f9db141a) for it [recommend by scott hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CoffeeScriptSassAndLESSSupportForVisualStudioAndASPNETWithTheMindscapeWebWorkbench.aspx)

or you could also look at [sassy studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85fa99a6-e4c6-4a1c-9f00-e6a8129b6f4d/view/Reviews).

all the best

Comment: I think i explained i wanted .sass, not .scss. I think the syntax is much cleaner, i don't wan't something more like css, because regualar css sucks.

Comment: None of the mindscape tools work for .sass, thank you though. I am done with that .NET project, finally.

Comment: SASS != SCSS, http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better

Comment: did sassy studio work? when mentioning that they were the same i was refering to this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5732683/181569