# CSS grouping :hover & :active

Tags: css

When I want to define css selector with `:hover` and `:active` I have to do:

```
#mainPage #content div.group:hover, #mainPage #content div.group:active {}
```

As one can see it contians repeated `#mainPage #content div.group` and can get messy. Is there a way to group it somehow like:

```
#mainPage #content div.group:hover:active {}
```

Comment: ***SCSS*** is your choice

Comment: What's SCSS? Do you mean SASS?

Comment: @Ultra no he doesn't : http://thesassway.com/editorial/sass-vs-scss-which-syntax-is-better

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Comment: Seems like your styling is about to announce the cold war of rules specificity.

Comment: @Adjit in an article comparing two styling language I expected to see at least a line of code ):

Answer (score 1):

In pure CSS there is not much of a better way to handle both more succinctly without adding a class or ids.

You could consider a CSS pre-compiler (like LESS or SASS/SCSS).

In [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/):

```css
#mainPage #content div.group {

    &:hover, &:active {
        color: red;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this should be relevant for somebody who needs this.

**CSS pseudo-class released by the end of 2020**

You can use `:is()` pseudo-class like so :

```
#mainPage #content div.group:is(:hover, :active) {
     /* your CSS code here */

}
```

Here is a little snippet to picture it :

```css
a:is(:hover, :focus) {
  color: red;
  outline: #5bc8ea dotted 4px;
  outline-offset: 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<a href="#hover-or-focus-me">Hover/Focus me</a>
```

More informations about `:is()` pseudo class here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is and here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/i/is/.

Works with most of the popular browsers (incompatible with IE, Opera and Safari  < 14) https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo.

It surely is more often used  to select elements than pseudo-classes like `:hover` or `:focus` but it will do the trick as I can't see any other solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest add `ID` for the element has class `group` and write below code will reduce the effort:

`#idname.group:hover, #idname.group:active{}`

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're using `#mainPage #content` before `div.group`?
Generally, it's not necessary to add that much 'specificity' to your selectors - it's better to instead, have unique classes.  So make sure that the class .group is only used for elements that you want to have the same styles.

If you do that, you should be able to style those elements just using

```
.group { styles here}
```

You might run into an issue now where if you try to override any of the styles you set like `#mainPage #content`, those will be *more specific* and so in effect 'stronger' than styles where you don't use the full list of parents.  If possible, change all your styles not to include the parent elements - this is also worthwhile in case you ever want to move an object to a different part of the html!

It's also, in general, advisable not to use id's (`#name`) to attach css styles - if possible, just use classes.  Unless you're doing javascript, you shouldn't have much need for id's.

Obviously there exceptions to the above, and for all I know you may have a perfectly good reason for doing things the way you have - in which case SASS (as suggested in a few other answers) is a good solution for you.

If not useful for you, I hope at least this answer might be useful for someone who might come along later - I've noticed that a lot of people newer to css don't realize how specificity of selectors works and end up making their styles a lot more complicated than necessary as a result!  :)

Comment: "realise" isn't a spelling mistake, I'm English, "realize" is american ;) 
(doesn't matter, just amused me that it'd been changed!)

Answer (score -1):

Why you use #mainPage #content? #content should be enough to find the div your looking for without the #mainPage.

Also id's are only allowed to be used once and not in multiple places like classes are. Id's are usually reserved for script assignments and not CSS. I would do

```
#content .group:hover{}
#content .group:active{}
```

Comment: Honestly, I would get rid of #content altogether and just add the class to the element you want to add this behavior to.

Answer (score -1):

if i understood correctly, you want a group of elements to act a certain way? manipulate the parent class then.

```
.parent-class:hover {
    .child-class {
       …desired styles go here
     }
}
```

Comment: this is not valid css, but something in the line of LESS or SASS

Comment: also note that the question is 8 years old