# is scss backwards compatible with less?

Tags: css, sass, less

Is scss backwards compatible with less?  I didn't think it was. For example, less prefixes variables with '@' whereas scss prefixes variables with '$'. But even if I replaced the variable prefix, I think there are certain functions/handling specific to each respective preprocessor.

A coworker was insisting that scss is backwards compatible with less.  I'm thinking that he may have been confused.  Less/scss is backwards compatible with css but I don't think that scss is backwards compatible with less.  Can you please confirm?

Comment: SCSS and LESS are completely different pre-processors. They are not compatible.

Comment: Sorry, it won't compatible with less.

Comment: While browsing SO, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5732683/2226315 which state SASS actually have a LESS parser.

Comment: @LiXinyang while that may have been true in 2011, it's no longer true

Answer (score 1):

For basic nested styling, LESS and Sass are generally compatible:

```
a {
    // A styles

    B {
        // B styles
    }

}
```

will compile to the same thing in both, and some built-in functions will give the same result.

But after that things are quite different. `&` behaves differently; Sass uses explicit `@mixin` mixins while in LESS all class definitions are mixins; the built-in functions are different; Sass has `if`, `for`, `each` and `while` directives, while LESS relies on `when` guards and mixins that recall themselves; etc.

---

For your reference

- LESS documentation is here http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature
- Sass documentation is a little trickier to navigate, but key pages are http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html and http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html