# Using bulma together with webpack

Tags: npm, webpack, bulma

I have [this](https://github.com/lony/js-npm-webpack) really simple webpack projects in with I now want to also use [bulma](http://bulma.io/) a css framework.

I installed the package via `npm i bulma` and tried to include it inside my `app.js`-file using the following snipped unsuccessfully:

```
import bulma from '~bulma/bulma.sass';
```

I also tried using a specific sass part, which also did not work:

```
import bulma from '~bulma/sass/base/_all';
```

Can you help me get this working or maybe point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your webpack config file so the sass loader also processes `sass` files, not only `scss` files.
Change this line: 
`test: /\.scss$/,` to `test: /\.(sass|scss)$/`

Comment: I use `import 'bulma/bulma.sass';` and I see no errors, does this work for you?

Comment: That was the solution, thank you! For the record I had an `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '~bulma/bulma.sass'` error.

Comment: If like me you want to know what is the difference between sass and scss look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Comment: Can I ask a follow up question? Considering I added all your improvements [here](https://github.com/lony/js-npm-webpack/tree/4bd3539f32b1915cc60cdb1ad4f2d150bf511205) I have the problem that my `npm run prod` version differece from `npm run dev` it seems something is different in the resulting css. Analysing it a bit deeper it may be the result of the PurifyCSSPlugin. Do you know what is wrong with my setup? How can I debug the cause more precisely?