# Why does this styling code not work between style tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I am trying to use ContextMenu.js to make a pop up menu shown but this code doesn't work. I took this code from here: https://codepen.io/Iamafro/pen/bLqyGd

I want the same functionality but it is not working when i am writing it in a single file.
This format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script> all the java script code from above link goes here </script>
  <style> all the css code from above link goes here </style>
</head>
<body>
   all the html code from above link goes here
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your full code. Also please note that the example features SCSS and not CSS code. Simply putting that in a style tag is definitely not going to work without some extra stuff.

Comment: To view the compiled CSS code you can click the down arrow in the CSS window on Codepen. Then you can put that code in a style tag.

Comment: This question is actually not about contextmenu.js or even a coding problem. It is about why the styling code from Codepen does not work in style tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work the way you expect because the styling code shown on Codepen is [SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46400443/4141482), not CSS. It needs to be compiled to CSS before presenting it to the browser.

Open the menu in the top right of the styling window on Codepen to show the compiled CSS.
[image]

You can put the CSS code between the `<style></style>` tags, and it will work just fine.

If you want to use SCSS, you have to pre-process it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you kept script before the body, so it is not finding the element, because it doesn't exist.

**Update the format to:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style> all the css code from above link goes here </style>
</head>
<body>
   all the html code from above link goes here
<script> all the java script code from above link goes here </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you have to pre-process the SCSS written, in order to get CSS properly.