# How to write a css-selection to select an element with ([myattr=a] || [myattr=b]) && [secondattr=s] in a one-liner?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to write a css-selection to select an element with ([myattr=a] || [myattr=b]) && [secondattr=s] in a one-liner?

At the end of the section 6.3.1. in https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation it's said

> The following selectors represent a DIALOGUE element whenever it has one of two different values for an attribute character:
>
> DIALOGUE[character=romeo]
>  DIALOGUE[character=juliet]

I don't get it working, simply. Is it possible in a one-liner at all?

Edit:
to select:

```
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="a" secondattr="s"></div></div>
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="b" secondattr="s"></div></div>
```

but not:

```
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="a" secondattr=""></div></div>
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="b" secondattr=""></div></div>
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="z" secondattr="s"></div></div>
```

In a one-liner prefeably, because `parentclass`and `another` are actually much longer and I need to use this on 5 different sorts of `secondattr`, from s to w.

Comment: @TemaniAfif If it's a div with class ch `div.ch` and I want it only to be selected when it's one child of `div.ca`, how to add this in front of the beforementioned selection? `div.ca div.ch [myattr=a][secondattr=s] [myattr=b][secondattr=s]` ?

Comment: you are almost, simply remove the space after div.ch and need `,` between both selector

Comment: What do those class names have to do with those attributes? Maybe it'd be easier if you just showed us the actual markup instead of trying to use sample names to illustrate your problem.

Comment: @john i added an answer for better explanation as the comment wasn't really good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select an element with ([myattr=a] || [myattr=b]) && [secondattr=s] in a one-liner, the only possible syntax is

```css
element[myattr='a'][secondattr='s'], element[myattr='b'][secondattr='s'] {..}
```

To address your later edit, the selector would be

```css
div.parentclass div.another[myattr='a'][secondattr='s'],
div.parentclass div.another[myattr='b'][secondattr='s'] {..}
```

For example,

```css
div {
  height: 1em; border: 1px solid;
}

div.parentclass div.another[myattr='a'][secondattr='s'],
div.parentclass div.another[myattr='b'][secondattr='s'] {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
to select:

<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="a" secondattr="s"></div></div>
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="b" secondattr="s"></div></div>

but not:

<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="a" secondattr=""></div></div>
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="b" secondattr=""></div></div>
<div class="parentclass"><div class="another" myattr="z" secondattr="s"></div></div>
```

Although I must say that `myattr` and `secondattr` are not allowed as attribute names, so using this in an actual production environment is not recommended. Use `data-...` attributes instead.

Note: if you think this is a bit long, and you need to target even more values for the attributes, you can use a preprocessor like SCSS, which allows you to write

```css
div.parentclass div.another[secondattr='s'] {
  &[myattr='a'], &[myattr='b'] {..}
}
```

so you don't have to repeat yourself.

Comment: Alright, so I have to repeat the `div.parentclass div.another` part sadly. Basically I suspected to have an error in the attribute selecting part, that's why I at first only posted that part. Though I still wonder what's meant by the W3.org paragraphed I cited then.

Comment: @John To not have to repeat yourself, you can use SCSS or similar. See edit.

Comment: @John The W3.org paragraph simply means that you can target any specific value of an attribute. So the two lines should be read as `DIALOGUE[character=romeo] {..}` and `DIALOGUE[character=juliet] {..}`, respectively. They are not two parts of a compound selector.

Comment: Is SCSS some W3 standard? I can'T even find it anywhere really, except for one stackoverflow answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654471/4550791 - Else that would be more or less I'm looking for. Just if there is a manual available for SCSS :)

Comment: Great! So the cited paragraph of the W3 page about `DIALOGUE[character=romeo] {..}` and `DIALOGUE[character=juliet] {..}` is clear now, too.

Comment: SCSS is not a W3C standard, but it's not that difficult to find. Are you sure you didn't have a typo?

Comment: If it's not a W3C standard, I first have to check where it is supported. I searched for quite a few keywords, but except once always with `w3.org` as one keyword. I will take a look, if I could find a manual, and if it runs in enough browsers. Else I have to stick with the repeating of the selectors. Ty all!

Comment: @John: SCSS (really, Sass) is a tool that you, as the author, can use to make writing CSS easier.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented above here is how you can do it:

```css
/* Select element where (a=='1' || a=='2') && b==2 
   which also is  (a==1 && b==2) || (a==2 && b==2)
*/

.container div[a='1'][b='2'],  /*(a==1 && b==2)*/
.container div[a='2'][b='2']   /*(a==2 && b==2)*/
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div a='1' b='2'>a</div>
  <div a='2' b='2'>b</div>
  <div a='3' b='3'>c</div>
  <div a='1' b='2'>d</div>
  <div a='4' b='3'>e</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

The same logic with your edited code:

```css
.parentclass .another[myattr=a][secondattr=s],.parentclass .another[myattr=b][secondattr=s] {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="another" myattr="a" secondattr="s">a</div>
</div>
<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="another" myattr="b" secondattr="s">b</div>
</div>
<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="another" myattr="a" secondattr="">c</div>
</div>
<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="another" myattr="b" secondattr="">d</div>
</div>
<div class="parentclass">
  <div class="another" myattr="z" secondattr="s">e</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to accept Mr. Lister's answer. (But I'm just browsing through some of your other answers on other questions, and upvote there, too. I like the css-coloured circle!)

Comment: @John yes sure no problem, you may accept the suitable answer :) but don't upvote a lot of answer as it may be seen as spam by the system :)