# Angular using scss/sass and css in the same project

Tags: css, angular, sass

I know it's possible to use both css and sass/scss in the same project.
I've looked at a SO question where this was asked, but from what I saw there was a lot of warnings popping up when using css as styleExt in the angular_cli.json file.

1. Is it recommendable to do so?
2. Should I rename all .css files to sass/scss?
3. What is best scss/sass, my guess is scss?
4. Any recommended procedure for the change/conversion, just renaming or is it necessary?

Comment: You an use css in scss/sass files.

Answer (score 5):

If you see angular-cli.json, `"styles":` is an array. So it should allow us to add multiple style files as a comma-separated array. That should remove the warnings.

However, I think it is better to have similar styles across your application. If you want to convert all your files to scss/sass, you can do so in the following way:

1. Rename your css file to .scss/.sass. Eg: `my-file.css` to `my-file.scss`.
2. In each corresponding `.component.ts` file, update the `styleUrls` with `.scss/.sass` filename. Eg: `styleUrls: ['my-file.css']` to `styleUrls: ['my-file.scss']`
3. Change the `styles:[ "styles.css"],` in `angular-cli.json` to `styles:["styles.scss],`, and that should do it!

You can learn more about sass/scss here: [Sass Lang Guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

Answer (score 2):

Rename your files from sass to scss. Scss is recognized worldwide, sass is simply a syntax of another language derived from css. The compilers recognize scss.

Use this command to change your project extensions

> ng set defaults.styleExt=scss

Manually change `.angular.json`:

```
"styleExt": "scss"
```

You can also change extensions manually, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** In local style case, it is not recommendable. Becasue it is too complex to handle both type for every components in angular. But for [global style](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles) , [defer load CSS](https://www.giftofspeed.com/defer-loading-css/) or [inline css](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery), you can choose that as option.

For **2. 3.** Use **.scss** if you already have some **.css** codes. Every **.css** code can be included in **.scss** files.  For more details, please read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5654447/6627660).

**4.** There are good descriptions in **Sourangshu**'s answer and https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#component-styles and [the link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)  in **1.**

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version of angular-cli you should use this for changing css to sass

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss
```

1. Is not recommendable, but this is possible.
2. Yes and change it in components.
3. They are similar. The main difference is in syntax.
   [What's the difference between SCSS and Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass)
4. You should have file for variables. And some folder for shared styles/mixins and other reusable things.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the best procedure was (Angular 5): Clone U'r repository first.

```
1. find . -name "*.css" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.css}".scss' - '{}' \;
2. Vscode: find .css replace to .scss
3. npm install to make sure that .css files in the node_modules are not messed up.
```

And it worked without ANY errors.

GO!