# Gulp 4 compilling scss creates empty css file, but sass compiles correctly

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass, node-sass

I have installed gulp@4.0.0, and gulp-sass@4.0.2, and latest gulp-cli in Windows

When I set path for src() to lookup for `'assets/css/src/**/*.sass'` files to create a stream, it compiles sass into css correctly.

But when I try to do so with `'assets/css/src/**/*.scss'` files, it creates corresponding .css file, but empty one.

When I put intentionally erroneous code in `.scss` file, it throws an error, so  gulp-sass actually does go through .scss file, but doesn't output the buffer into css code.

Even when I run node-sass manually to compile the script, it produces same issue, so it might be related more to node-sass as compiler.

note:
Syntax for both .scss and .sass are correct, and correct extensions are being used.

This is my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");


let paths = {
    css : {
        src  : 'assets/css/src/**/*.scss',
        dest : 'assets/css/dist'           
    }
};


function style() { 

    return (
        gulp
            .src(paths.css.src)
            .pipe(sass())
            .on("error", sass.logError)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.css.dest))
    );
}


// $ gulp style
exports.style = style;
```

Comment: You could try removing the brackets in your return statement.

Comment: @TheDancingCode, thanks, but that doesn't have any impact. As I have mentioned, when I set for path to stream the .sass files instead of .scss, it compiles correctly, but .scss returns empty buffer

Comment: Try moving the 'dist' directory outside the 'assets'..making the 'src' and 'dest' in different locations. I usually create 'source' and 'public' (dist) directory both on the root.

Comment: @Shakespear, I tried that before, it produces same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: It turns out that only style block that had some property was commented, thus causing .scss file return empty output, and sass won't compile empty blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be when you change the file extension to `.scss` the content is still using the old style indented syntax.

**.SASS** indented syntax

```
body
    background-color: red;

    h1
        font-size: 2.5rem;
```

**.SCSS** syntax

```
body {
    background-color: red;

    h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }
}
```

Make sure you're using the right syntax per extension.

You can read more about [Sass Indented Syntax](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html) and the difference between [**SASS** and **SCSS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass)

Comment: Thanks, but I use correct syntax and correct extension. As I am testing further, I tried to run manually node-sass compiling, and it looks like it is issue narrowed to node-sass. In other words, the suggestion in on answer is not an issue. Thanks anyway for effort.