# Mixins in Bulma is quite different from official Sass Documents. Can you help me understand?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, bulma

In the official SASS mixins, it shows

```
@mixin transform($property) {
 -webkit-transform: $property;
 -ms-transform: $property;
 transform: $property;
}
```

But when I downloaded Bulma, their mixins style is quite different. Can you help me understand or direct me to the relevant article?

```
=unselectable
  -webkit-touch-callout: none
  -webkit-user-select: none
  -moz-user-select: none
  -ms-user-select: none
user-select: none

%unselectable
  +unselectable
```

Here I'm not able to understand the usage of =, % and +. (Maybe % is to extend but not sure on it.)

Answer (score 0):

=, % and + symbols are sass syntax of sass-lang.

There are two variants of syntax used in sass-lang. One is scss and other is sass.
bulma uses sass syntax. See [What's the difference between SCSS and Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass) for difference between two variants.

https://sass-lang.com/guide : displays guide in scss and sass both.