# In SCSS, what does % symbol indicate?

Tags: css, sass

What does % indicate in scss?

Use of % in context: (source: https://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/GrpqB?editors=1100)

```
@import "compass/css3";

.box{
  margin: 5em auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  line-height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

%box__dir{
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;          
  text-align: center;
  line-height: inherit;
  transition:transform .4s ease;
}
```

What does the percentage sign before "box_dir" indicate?

Comment: Well, SCSS and SASS are clearly different. A person that has no knowledge of SASS would be looking for a question about SCSS not SASS. What more is there to say; this is not a duplicate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Comment: @TemaniAfif For a person who doesn't about SASS, having this question would help him out a lot. He might see the question you marked my question as a duplicate of and think that it wouldn't help him because it's about SASS -- remember, he doesn't know that SASS and SCSS is largely the same. (Not long ago, I was in that situation)

Comment: I still don't see the issue of marking as duplicate. Closing a question doesn't mean deleting the question. A person can still find your question and the below answer and he will also understand that SASS is the same as SCSS. The comments we are also writing now will make anyone who will find this question better understand that both are the same

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In `SCSS`, the `%` indicates a [placeholder selector](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/understanding-placeholder-selectors).

> [Placeholders] are very similar to class selectors, but instead of using a
>   period (`.`) at the start, the percent character (`%`) is used.
>   Placeholder selectors have the additional property that they *will not*
>   show up in the generated CSS, only the selectors that extend them will
>   be included in the output.

So if you included this in your `SCSS` somewhere but never used (extended) it, it will not appear in your generated `CSS`.

```css
%box__dir {
 position:absolute;
 width:inherit;
 height:inherit;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:inherit;
 transition:transform .4s ease;
}
```

Once you use the `placeholder`, it will appear in your generated `CSS` as expected.

```css
.something {
  color: red;
  @extend %box__dir;
}
```

**Generated `CSS`:**

```css
.something {
  color: red;
  position:absolute;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:inherit;
  transition:transform .4s ease;
}
```

Comment: "@extend $box__dir" - the dollar symbol indicates it's a variable right?

Comment: @sebastiannielsen That was a typo. Fixed. The link I included in my answer has several real-world examples that should help you beyond the scope of the answer.

Comment: What is the difference between mixins and % ? If a mixin is not used in any class it also is not gerated, right?

Comment: @AleksGrunwald Good explanation [here](https://medium.com/@linker21/scss-placeholders-vs-mixins-fe79b9dbb6d5) with practical examples towards the end of the article.