# Why we are using SASS, even we are using SCSS?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am working already by SCSS in my projects but I'm still confused.

Why we are using  SASS even we have SCSS, and can we use SASS and SCSS at the same projects, it will work at the same projects?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sass has two syntaxes. The most commonly used syntax is known as “SCSS” (for “Sassy CSS”), and is a superset of CSS3’s syntax. This means that every valid CSS3 stylesheet is valid SCSS as well. SCSS files use the extension .scss.

The second, older syntax is known as the indented syntax (or just “.sass”). Inspired by Haml’s terseness, it’s intended for people who prefer conciseness over similarity to CSS. Instead of brackets and semicolons, it uses the indentation of lines to specify blocks. Files in the indented syntax use the extension .sass.

**SCSS**

```
$blue: #3bbfce;

$margin: 16px;

.content-navigation { 

  border-color: $blue;

  color: darken($blue, 9%);

}

.border {

  padding: $margin / 2; 

 margin: $margin / 2;

 border-color: $blue;

}
```

**SASS**

```
$blue: #3bbfce

$margin: 16px


.content-navigation

  border-color: $blue

  color: darken($blue, 9%)


.border

  padding: $margin / 2

  margin: $margin / 2

  border-color: $blue
```

**CSS**

```
.content-navigation {

  border-color: #3bbfce;

  color: #2b9eab;

}

.border {

  padding: 8px;

  margin: 8px;

  border-color: #3bbfce;

}
```

Comment: tnx so much ı understand very well.

Comment: Thank you. This is the only answer I found that clearly explains the difference between each.

Comment: `calc(var(--margin) / 2)` is now standard CSS, but for `darken` i've only found `filter: brightness(9%)`