# SCSS is a superset of CSS with "a few small exceptions" - what are they?

Tags: css, sass

As of today, the [SASS syntax page](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss) says

> The SCSS syntax uses the file extension .scss. **With a few small exceptions**, it’s a superset of CSS, which means essentially all valid CSS is valid SCSS as well

However, there seems to be no documentation regarding what the "small exceptions" are. Can these be found anywhere except the SASS/SCSS source code?

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/special-functions

Comment: I don't understand how this question could be improved by someone who doesn't already know the answer.