# 'Invalid CSS' error when loading external font into SASS

Tags: css, sass, fonts

I'm getting an error when trying to load an external font in my SASS file. Here is the code to load the font-face from all.sass (which is in the same directory as leaguespartan-bold-webfont.woff and leaguespartan-bold-webfont.woff2):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'league_spartanbold';
    src: url('leaguespartan-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('leaguespartan-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

And the error message when I try to run this locally:

```
@font-face {
           ^
      Invalid CSS after "@font-face {": expected "}", was "{"
```

Comment: What is the extension of the file? Is it `.sass` or `.scss`?

Comment: It's .sass but I may change it to .scss

Comment: Can you check compiling the same code with `.scss` extension?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the file extension `.scss`, which is for the CSS-like syntax for Sass.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654471/864799

Otherwise, you need to switch the font-face declaration to use the whitespace significant `.sass` syntax, which doesn’t include braces.