# SassError: Invalid CSS after "" with Rails 6, Webpacker, and Vue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpacker, sass-loader

I've just started a fresh **rails-6** project with **webpacker** and **vue**. I wanted to have the vue-component styles in **sass**, but the **sass-loader** throughs:

> Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js)
> SassError: Invalid CSS after "": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".foo"

Has anyone seen this before? Or maybe, how can I debug what goes wrong here?

#### Component `foo.vue`

```
<template>...</template>
<script>...</script>
<style lang="sass">
  .foo
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
</style>
```

Removing the initial indention of the `sass` code does not help.

#### Versions

- rails 6.1.3.1
- webpacker 5.2.1
- node 14.16.1

#### Project setup

```
rails new --database=postgresql --skip-test foo
rails webpacker:install:vue
yarn add vue-turbolinks
rails webpacker:install:coffee
yarn add coffee-loader@1
yarn add sass-loader@10
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "@tabler/core": "tabler/tabler",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "coffee-loader": "1",
    "coffeescript": "1.12.7",
    "sass-loader": "10",
    "tabler": "^1.0.0-alpha.8",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
    "vue-select": "^3.11.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-turbolinks": "^2.2.2"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

I've also added `vue-select`, `bootstrap`, and `tabler`. But I don't think they will interfere.

#### Webpack configuration `config/webpack/environment.js`

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const coffee =  require('./loaders/coffee')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const vue = require('./loaders/vue')

environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())
environment.loaders.prepend('vue', vue)
environment.loaders.prepend('coffee', coffee)
module.exports = environment
```

#### Layout `application.html.haml`

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Foo
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = csp_meta_tag
    = stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
    = javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'
  %body
    #vue_app
      = yield
```

#### Pack `packs/application.js`

```js
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

import 'bootstrap'
import '@tabler/core'

import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'

Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue_app',
    data: () => {
      return {}
    },
    components: {}
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sass vs. SCSS

There are [two syntax variants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654471/2066546):

> There are two syntaxes available for Sass. The first, known as **`SCSS (Sassy CSS)`** and used throughout this reference, is an **extension of the syntax of CSS**. This means that every valid CSS stylesheet is a valid SCSS file with the same meaning. This syntax is enhanced with the Sass features described below. Files using this syntax have the **.scss** extension.
>
> The second and **older syntax**, known as the **`indented syntax (or sometimes just “Sass”)`**, provides a more concise way of writing CSS. It **uses indentation rather than brackets** to indicate nesting of selectors, and **newlines rather than semicolons** to separate properties. Files using this syntax have the **.sass** extension.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654471/2066546, https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax

### Which syntax does the `sass-loader` use?

The [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) chooses the syntax according to the file extension by default:

> The `indentedSyntax` option has `true` value for the `sass` extension.

This means that the original sass syntax (indented syntax) is only used if the file extension is `.sass`. Within the vue component, which has the extension `.vue`, the `sass-loader` uses the newer "scss" syntax by default.

### How to configure `sass-loader` to use the sass syntax (indented syntax)?

The [sass-loader documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sassoptions) has instructions on how to specify `indentedSyntax: true` in the webpack configuration.

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                indentedSyntax: true
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

However, with [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker), the webpack configuration is composed automatically. So, one needs to [modify the existing configuration object](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/756#issuecomment-327148547):

```js
// config/webpack/environment.js

const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

// To get an overview, have a look at `environment.loaders`.
console.log(environment.loaders)

const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const sassConfig = environment.loaders.find(el => el.key == 'sass')
const sassLoader = sassConfig.value.use.find(el => el.loader == 'sass-loader')

sassLoader.options = merge(sassLoader.options, {
  sassOptions: {
    indentedSyntax: true
  }
})

module.exports = environment
```

This requires [webpack-merge](https://github.com/survivejs/webpack-merge):  `yarn add webpack-merge`.

I'm sure there are better ways to do it. Please feel free to add answers or comments!

Answer (score 0):

Sass works with curly braces:
.foo {
margin: 0
}

Comment: Thanks! To be clear: I do want to use the `sass` syntax, not the `scss` syntax. See: https://sass-lang.com/guide. Do I somehow need to specify this, now?

Comment: Ah, I see. I do not know webpacker, but can you overwrite or extend the webpack configuration somehow? Maybe you have to set the indentWidth and / or indentedSyntax to true: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#sassoptions

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>` on your root HTML file.

I think it will work.

Comment: Thanks! I had this in my layout, already. I'll update my question to include the `application.html.haml` layout file and the `application.js` pack.

Comment: Can you add the webpack config too on your question?

Comment: Thanks, I'll add the `config/webpack/environment.js`, but I didn't change it manually with respect to the files generated by webpacker.

Comment: I can see you are not loading sass-loader. you can try to load the sass-loader. but I am not sure how to do this like a option of vue-loader.

`module.exports = {
  test: /\.vue(\.erb)?$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "vue-loader",
      options: { extract_css: true },
    },
  ],
};`

Comment: I think this is done by webpacker already: https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/package/rules/sass.js. Also, my `application.sass` pack is also sass and this works fine.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/how-to-import-a-sass-file-into-every-vue-component-in-an-app/
Please refer this url