# What is the name of the technology - SASS or SCSS, what would you write on your CV?

Tags: css, sass

As far as I know - the name of the technology is **SASS** and it supports two file types:

```
.scss

.sass
```

and on my CV I wrote that I have experience with SASS.

BUT on one job interview for front-end web developer,
the guy interviewing me said to me -

*"There is an error in your CV, 
 you wrote that you have been working with SASS, 

but that's not correct, you made a mistake and probably meant to say - SCSS.

SASS and SCSS are very different and I don't think that you ever used SASS 

which is far more complicated"*

I have experience with both file types, 
 I know the difference and yes they have a slightly different syntax

BUT what is the official name of the technology, 
not the file types, the technology / skill you would list 
more correctly on a CV, LinkedIn etc?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the `resume` tag.

Comment: Here's a helpful resource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass

Comment: This is already answered in the question linked above. But the remark you got from that person is weird anyway, there are no significant functional differences between these two syntaxes. (Personally I would just list "SCSS" in my CV, but I don't think it really matters.)

Comment: Thank you for the links - but have you read more than just the title ? none of those questions / answers speak about what to write on a CV -  what is the official name of the the technology. They are about the differences which as I said I already know.

Comment: I'd check out [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass/), match the examples to the skillset you're trying to project on your CV and go from there as to which to use.

Comment: I'd put SCSS on the CV. While it's not the name of the technology, it's less prone to misinterpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the terms you are looking for are CSS-"superset" and CSS-"preprocessor".

Also there is not a huge difference between SASS and SCSS. One uses a so called "indented syntax" which means that you don't need curly braces and semi-colons.

So you really dodged a bullet when someone from a company says that "they are vastly different".

Comment: yes, exactly right, I agree thank you