# Turn all SASS code into CSS in Nuxt project

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I have a project where part of the code is written in SASS. I want to get rid of SASS and work with vanilla CSS, so I'm trying to find a programatic way to turn all my SASS parts into CSS, or at least having a way to do it programatically in each component that I'm working on. At the end of the process, I would remove all SASS dependencies and have just CSS in my code.

Any hints will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

**Edit**:
The SASS/SCSS is written in component, pages and layout .vue files inside a `<style lang="sass">` or `<style lang="scss">` tag. Inside them, there are some imports with the format

```
@import './folder/css/stuff';

.head-navigation
```

**Edit 2**:
Proposed solution doesn't work due to error

> Error: Invalid CSS after "@import './folder/css/stuff';": expected 1
> selector or at-rule, was ".head-navigation"\n

check live example [here](https://replit.com/@jesus38/Nuxt-SASS-3)

Comment: Does the SASS import mixins and variables from other files, or is it standalone?

Comment: They import mixins from other files as well.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how the project is structured? You've tagged it `vue.js` does this mean the SASS is all in .vue template files? Or are there also standalone .scss files?

Comment: @jla see my edit

Comment: Why not just use [Sass: Playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/)? You'll need to manually copy/paste the sass contents into it and then the result back into the project but, still, I doubt it will be more effort than what you invested so far in this question. If you use mixins, just go to source and place those into the playground as well, where needed.

Comment: @tao that approach can work if you want to convert few files. For 500+ files it is not a good approach and can be very error-prone imho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment and code, I can surmise, you want to conver only the part of `vue` file which has `sass/scss` code inside of it. If I had to achieve this requirement, I would write a custom script which:

1. would iterate over all the `.vue` files.
2. find if there is a style tag with language as `sass`.
3. Replace the content with compiled `css` code.

For achieving above steps I will be using three packages.

- [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass): For converting `sass/scss` code to `css`.
- [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra): For file-handling and as an alternative to native `fs` module. You can go ahead with `fs` module as well.
- [vue-template-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler): A parser which understands Vue components. Here, I could have used `regex` as well but usually it's not a good idea to parse a language using regular expressions. Why? It has to do with some theoretical concepts of computation. Please [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/19090048).

This is how it looks in code:

```js
// convert-sass.js
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');
const sass = require('node-sass');
const compiler = require('vue-template-compiler');

const vueDirectory = './src'; // path to all your .vue files.

function convertSASSinVueFiles(dir) {
  // 1. iterate over all files inside the directory with .vue extension
  fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {
    const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
    if (fs.lstatSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
      convertSASSinVueFiles(filePath);
    } else if (path.extname(file) === '.vue') {
      convertSASSinVueComponent(filePath);
    }
  });
}
function convertSASSinVueComponent(file) {

  const content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
  // Parse the vue file
  const parsedComponent = compiler.parseComponent(content);
  /* 2. Find if there is a style tag with the lang attribute as sass.
        You can modify this as per your need. */
  if (parsedComponent.styles.length > 0 && 
        (parsedComponent.styles[0].lang === 'sass' ||
         parsedComponent.styles[0].lang === 'scss')) {
    const sassCode = parsedComponent.styles[0].content;
    // convert the sass code to css.
    const cssCode = sass.renderSync(
      {
        data: sassCode,
        includePaths: ['./path/to/your/partials']
      }
    ).css.toString();
    // Replace the sass content with css code.
    const updatedContent = content.
                             replace(/<style.*lang="s[ac]ss".*>([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/, 
                              `<style>${cssCode}</style>`);
    fs.writeFileSync(file, updatedContent);
  }
}
convertSASSinVueFiles(vueDirectory);
```

**NOTE 1:** The replace regex i.e. `/<style.*lang="s[ac]ss".*>([\s\S]*?)<\/style>/` currently checks for both `scss` and `sass` syntaxes. You can adjust it as per your need.

**NOTE 2:** In case you're using [partials](https://sass-lang.com/guide/#partials), you just need to include one of the properties which is provided by scss-compiler i.e. ***[**includePaths**](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/legacyfileoptions/#includePaths)*** option to the compiler.

**EDIT:**

Initially, the code that I provided would convert all `.scss` syntax to `.css` one. Now looking at your latest comment, it can be seen that you're using `.sass` syntax and not `.scss` syntax. You can refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654471/19090048)** post to read the difference between their syntax. In short, ***one uses indentation and other uses curly braces just like our css rules do***.

However, a good news is that there is a single compiler which can convert both the syntaxes and we're already using that initially. You just need to provide an extra option to `renderSync()` function i.e. *[indentedSyntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax/#the-indented-syntax)* and set it's value to *true*. Something like:

```js
const isSass = parsedComponent.styles[0].lang === 'sass';
const cssCode = sass.renderSync(
    {
      data: sassCode,
      includePaths: ['./path/to/your/partials'],
      indentedSyntax: isSass // set to true for sass syntax
    }
  ).css.toString();
```

**NOTE 3:** You might also want to tweak the path of partials inside your `includePaths` option as per your requirement. Note, if you provide `includePath` option with paths, the compiler would look inside that specific directory for the partials and would ignore the relative path inside your `@import` rule. For example, say I provided `./src/sass` to the array of `includePaths` option and in my `scss/sass` code if the partial is imported as `@import './src/sass/someDir/typography';` I would get an error of file not found. For this particular case you might want to remove the `includePaths` option from the script.

***[CODE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/Nuxt-SASS#convert-sass.js)***

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here the thing is that I have to convert .vue files, that has just a part of SASS/SCSS, being the rest html and JS. You can see a working example here https://replit.com/@jesus38/Nuxt-SASS#src/example.vue

Comment: @Joe82 I think it's working right, why not accepting the answer?

Comment: @nmfzone sorry, had two busy days and didn't have time to check. Will do it today

Comment: here's what I did so far. Changed all imports to this syntax `@import './folder/css/stuff';` (note the semicolon and the quotes) in order to make it work. Now it fails in this step: `Error: Invalid CSS after "@import './folder/css/stuff';": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".head-navigation"\n` I checked this issue, but in my .vue file, the indentation seems correct (see my edit in the OP)

Comment: @Joe82 I have edited my answer to include your requirement. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, unfortunately, it yields the same error than before. I will give you the bounty, but I cannot mark it as right though.

Comment: @Joe82 can you somehow replicate this issue or reproduce this issue please? I can help you solve this and I want to solve it. This looks solvable. It seems like there is a wrong css/scss that is written because the correct scss will be converted to css by using above script.

Comment: @Joe82 I have tried to replicate your issue with a brand new partial `_lists.scss` which is inside a folder. It works perfectly for me. Please see the update code demo. Also can you please add some more scss from the file where you're getting this error? I can try to replicate that as well

Comment: @mandy8055 sorry for the delay (last week was busy as hell). I managed to replicate the issue here, let me know if you need more info https://replit.com/@jesus38/Nuxt-SASS-3

Comment: @Joe82 Alright. Now I got your final issue. I have updated my answer. Please have a look. In the code demo I provided both type of files i.e. `.scss`(example.vue) and `.sass`(example2.vue) and included the above code which you replicated. Now if you run the convert-sass script(`node convert-sass.js`) it will convert both of them. Please let me know if you want a standalone script for `sass` and not `scss`. I provided a complete solution which would work for both:)

Comment: Finally got it working, just had a few issues with imports and deprecated function. Thanks for that!